# Unir arreglo de frames en Angular

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Consumo una API que me devuelve un video en el siguiente formato:

```
{
  audio:"data:audio/mp3;base64,//tgx...",
  video:{
    "frames":[
     {"data":"/9j/4AA...","position":0,"time":0.157}, 
     {"data":"/9j/4AA...","position":1,"time":0.105},
     ....
     {"data":"/9j/4AA...","position":n},
    ],
    "fps":9.18,
    "duration":20
  }
}
```

Como se puede observar en el objeto el audio y el video se encuentran separados, el audio en formato mp3 y el video en un frame, Este video es necesario enviarlo via POST a NodeJS, la pregunta es como puedo unirlo usando JS (cliente).

Comment: Lo que yo haria es guardar el valor de audio en una const y el valor de los frames en otra const luego declarar otra variable y unir esos 2 valores con `${}` es lo que se me ocurre viendo tu problema.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el formato que deseas que tenga la data?

Comment: @gugadev podria ser un mp4 o un wbmp

Comment: A ver, ¿lo que tú quieres es añadirle el audio a todos los vídeos?

Comment: No, lo que quiero lograr en unir todos esos frames que entiendo son imagenes del video (screenshots) y ponerle su audio, con el fin de tener un binario un blob o un buffer para poder enviarlo via Post a Node

Answer (score 0):

Hola así lo pude resolver como lo mencionas de unir esas 2 partes.

```js
const data = {
  audio: "data:audio/mp3;base64,//tgx...",
  video: {
    frames: [
      { data: "/9j/4AA...", position: 0, time: 0.157 },
      { data: "/9j/4AA...", position: 1, time: 0.105 },
      { data: "/9j/4AA...", position: 23 }
    ],
    fps: 9.18,
    duration: 20
  }
};

const mp3 = data.audio;


let frames = [];

frames = data.video.frames;

for(let i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    let framesEstructura = frames[i].data;
    let union = `${mp3}${framesEstructura}`;
    console.log(union);
}
```

```html
Así lo resolvi mira el javascript y la consola.
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero creo que se esta agregando el audio por cada frame, cierto ?, es posible generar un blob con la union de estos frames ?